# Loading JSON using Python Requests wrong type

Tags: python, json, python-requests, marklogic

I'm trying to load some data to ML using Python. This works ok but the type is set to 'T' and not to 'J' within ML.
I'd like to resolve this. The header setting seems to be just for show so how do I do this?

```
# Sending data
data = {'meting': '477', 'bericht': '473', 'plant': '01'}
url = 'http://server:8000/v1/documents?database=thijsPlantjes&extension=json'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, json = json.dumps(data), auth=HTTPDigestAuth('plantje', 'password'), headers = headers)
```

Comment: The whole point of the `json` keyword argument is that it does the JSON serialisation for you, including setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `json` parameter, [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) will serialize for you, so you don't need to `json.dumps` yourself.

And it will also set content-type for you; you can drop `headers` keyword argument.

```
r = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('plantje', 'password'))
```

According to [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
>   using the `json` parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
>   encoded automatically:

Comment: It also sets the `Content-Type` header, the `headers` argument here is entirely redundant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thank you for the information. I updated the answer accordingly.